# Use of the reverse triangle inequality in epsilon proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, triangles

I'm new to analysis and trying to prove something about a converging series.

Now I want to get from $|x_{n}-\bar{x}| < \frac{|\bar{x}|}{2}$ to the following statement $|x_{n}| > \frac{|\bar{x}|}{2}$ using the reverse triangle inequality, but I just don't seem to get it right.

As for as my knowledge goes, the reverse inequality states that $||b|-|a|| \leq |b|-|a|$. Any suggestions on how to apply this?

PS: it is a bout a converging sequence $x_{n}$ with limit $\bar{x}$.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using them: per the description in the algebraic-geometry tag, that tag is inappropriate for this question.

Comment: It's likely a typo, but perhaps you were having difficulty because you have the reverse inequality sign mixed around. Your text says $||b|-|a|| \leq |b|-|a|$ (which won't be true if $|b| \lt |a|$), while it should be $||b|-|a|| \geq |b|-|a|$ instead. Also, you don't need to use the absolute values of $a$ and $b$ on the LHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost right there. Note that
$$|\bar x| - |x_n|\le |x_n-\bar x| < \frac{|\bar x|}2$$
gives you exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I could not see this... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$
|x_n| - |\overline{x}| \leq |x_n - \overline{x}| < \frac{|\overline{x}|}{2}
$$
and:

$$
|\overline{x}| -|x_n|  \leq |x_n - \overline{x}| < \frac{|\overline{x}|}{2}
$$

by definition of $||x| - |y||$.Hence:

$$
|x_n| > |\overline{x}| - \frac{|\overline{x}|}{2} = \frac{|\overline{x}|}{2}
$$

Comment: makes perfect sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The 'reverse' triangle inequality states the following: for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$
\begin{align*}
|x-y|\geq |x|-|y|.
\end{align*}
To see this, notice that 
\begin{align*}
|x|-|y|=|x-y+y|-|y|\leq |x-y|+|y|-|y|=|x-y|,
\end{align*}
where the inquality follows from the normal triangle inequality. 
Now, if you have $|x_n-\bar{x}|<\frac{|\bar{x}|}{2}$ then this means that 
\begin{align*}
|\bar{x}|-|x_n|\leq\frac{|\bar{x}|}{2},
\end{align*}
and so by adding $|x_n|$ to both sides and subtracting $\frac{|\bar{x}|}{2}$ the result follows.